# Supposing that a quantum system is in a degenerate ground-state, is it valid to call this a "superposition" of the possible groundstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, ground-state

According to the adiabatic theorem, a quantum system can be prepared in the ground-state of some Hamiltonian $H_f$ if it starts in the ground state of some Hamiltonian $H_I$ and is varied "slowly" enough (w.r.t. the energy gap). If $H_f$ is n-degenerate, is it accurate to say that the system is in an equal "superposition" of these ground-states?

If so, is it possible to construct an "unequal" superposition of ground-states using the adiabatic theorem or some weird phenomena at 0K?